# Replacing pattern with pattern+incrementing number

Tags: shell, replace, awk, increment

Here is a snippet of the text files I want to edit:

```
"> RECORD:W7_S7_L001_R2_001_43549049:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
AGGCTCGAACTTCCTTTGGATGAACTCCAAAAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAACACCTTACAA

"> RECORD:W41_S41_L001_R2_001_36873913:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
TGCCTCAAACTTCCGTGGATTAAACATCCACAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAGCCGTCAACCAA

"> RECORD:W32_S56_L001_R2_001_29095773:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
TGCCTCAAACTTCCTTATGCTTGCACATAAAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAGACTCCCTATTTA
```

Now I want to replace every ">" with ">$a" and then incrementing "$a++".
I found a solution that almost worked:

```
>awk '/>/{sub(/start/,++n);{print}'
```

But this only replaces the > with a number without the >.

I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to believe that with just a glance at a man page and maybe a quick google you couldn't figure out how to fix the code snippet you had found to do what you want but here it is:

```
$ awk '/>/{sub(/>/,">"++n)}{print}' file
">1 RECORD:W7_S7_L001_R2_001_43549049:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
AGGCTCGAACTTCCTTTGGATGAACTCCAAAAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAACACCTTACAA

">2 RECORD:W41_S41_L001_R2_001_36873913:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
TGCCTCAAACTTCCGTGGATTAAACATCCACAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAGCCGTCAACCAA

">3 RECORD:W32_S56_L001_R2_001_29095773:wang1141_Nem_0425_6
TGCCTCAAACTTCCTTATGCTTGCACATAAAGTCCCTCTAAGAAGTTAGACTCCCTATTTA
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Besides `"` being the string delimiter, you can never use `'`s inside a script that's delimited by `'`s. Please click on the check mark next to it if/when you accept an answer.